# Stop EIdWinsockStubError, WSACancelBlockingCall error appearing when closing Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, activex, winsock

I have an ASP.NET application where one of the pages hosts a 3rd party ActiveX control.  A condition can sometimes occur with the ActiveX control that causes the following error message to be displayed in a Windows dialog box when Internet Explorer is closed:

```
Exception EIdWinsockStubError in module CADVIE~1.OCX at 0029A808.

Error on call to Winsock2 library function WSACancelBlockingCall: 
Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed.
```

Without any intervention from the suppliers of the ActiveX control can I suppress this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EIdWinsockStubError` is an exception thrown by the [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org) library when it fails to dynamically load a WinSock function using `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`.  In this case, something in the OCX is calling Indy's `WSACancelBlockingCall()` stub after Indy has already unloaded WinSock from memory.  Indy itself does not use `WSACancelBlockingCall()` at all, so it has to be a bug in the OCX's own code.

Comment: Thanks - I could not find a way to handle this.  Fortunately the error was fixed in the ActiveX control in a subsequent release